# Excel, loop through XLSM files and copy row to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

**The main issue I am having with this code now is handling errors with the xlsm files I am opening.
I have no edit rights to the VB code on these files.  Is there a way to skip over a file if the vb errors out on it?**

I have a folder with approx 99 xlsm files that I am looking to loop through each file and copy let's just say row 14 from each workbook and paste it into a separate workbook as a summary.
Here's what I have so far; the only problem is it copies a blank row. When I stepped through the VB I could see that it doesn't run the macro on the xlsm file it opens. Anyone know some code that will help me here?

```
 Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim NRow As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet.
Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
FolderPath = "C:\Users\dredden2\Documents\SHAREPOINT ARCHIVING\PAGESETUP\TEST\"

' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
NRow = 2

' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
FileName = DIR(FolderPath & "*.xlsm")

' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
Do While FileName <> ""
    ' Open a workbook in the folder
    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
    WorkBk.Application.EnableEvents = True
    WorkBk.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WorkBk.Application.Run _
    "'" & FileName & "'!auto_open"
    ' Set the cell in column A to be the file name.
    SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName

    ' Set the source range to be B14 through BF14.
    ' Modify this range for your workbooks.
    ' It can span multiple rows.
    Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Sheets("Retrospective Results").Range("B14:BF14")

    ' Set the destination range to start at column B and
    ' be the same size as the source range.
    Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
    Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
       SourceRange.Columns.Count)

    ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
    DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

    ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
    NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

    ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

    ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
    FileName = DIR()
Loop

' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all
' data is readable.
SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit

 WorkBk.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
SummarySheet.SaveAs FileName:= _
    FolderPath & "\SummarySheet\SummarySheet.xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
 End Sub
```

Comment: What line is causing you trouble?

Comment: Actually, I just realized this code works; but doesn't seem very efficient. I added the row    
     WorkBk.Application.Run _
         "'" & FileName & "'!auto_open"
which invokes the macro on each xlsm file.  I was just trying to figure out if there was a more efficient method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends *where* you run this macro. Consider opening another workbook and placing this macro behind a sheet or module, having it interact with all 99 source files and Summary destination file. Alternatively, you can run everything from the Summary workbook, changing `Workbooks.Add` to the `ActiveWorkbook`.

Below is a slightly revised VBA code. Rather than work with ranges, try copy and paste row by row. Also, no need for invoking the `Application.Run` macro

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim SummaryWkb As Workbook, SourceWkb As Workbook
    Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet, SourceWks As Worksheet
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As Variant
    Dim NRow As Long

    Set SummaryWkb = Workbooks.Add()
    Set SummarySheet = SummaryWkb.Worksheets(1)

    FolderPath = "C:\Users\dredden2\Documents\SHAREPOINT ARCHIVING\PAGESETUP\TEST\"
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath)

    NRow = 1
    While (FileName <> "")
        If Right(FileName, 4) = "xlsm" Then

        Set SourceWkb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
        Set SourceWks = SourceWkb.Sheets("Retrospective Results")

        'FILE NAME COPY
        SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow) = FileName

        'DATA ROW COPY
        SourceWks.Range("B14:BF14").Copy
        SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        SourceWkb.Close False
        NRow = NRow + 1

        End If
    FileName = Dir
    Wend

    SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
    SummaryWkb.SaveAs FileName:=FolderPath & "\SummarySheet\SummarySheet.xlsx" _
           , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    MsgBox "Data successfully extracted!", vbInformation

    Set SourceWkb = Nothing
    Set SourceWks = Nothing
    Set SummarySheet = Nothing
    Set SummaryWkb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: New issue with this code; if the xlsm file it opens has an error in its vb (which is not vb I can modify) my code bails.  Is there a way to create an ON ERROR handling after my code opens the xlsm file(s)?

Answer (score 0):

In my case for optimization VBA we used this code before:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
Application.EnableAutoComplete = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.EnableLivePreview = False
Application.EnableMacroAnimations = False
sourcesheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
destinationSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
isHidden = Sheets(destinationSheetName).Visible
Sheets(destinationSheetName).Visible = True
```

And this code after:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
Application.EnableAutoComplete = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.EnableLivePreview = True
Application.EnableMacroAnimations = True
sourcesheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
destinationSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
Sheets(destinationSheetName).Visible = isHidden
```

Most important thing is to work with visible sheet.
In my case code execution time on invisible sheet was a couple minutes. In case of visible sheet it took 10 sec. So, we change visibility dynamically.